# AngularJS - cannot change value of a inputbox

Tags: angularjs

The code below changes an input value from 100 to 200 using Angular. When using my controller to change the value of an input box I am getting a TypeError.

```
<div ng-controller="FooController" ...>
      <input ng-model="foo.price" type="text" name="price"  class="price" id="price-min" ng-init="foo.price = '100'" />
    ...
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
Foobar.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

setPrice($scope);


function setPrice($scope) {
var price = '200';
    $scope.foo.price = price;

}]);
```

error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'price_min' of undefined

I can provide additional code or information if needed

Comment: can u post a fiddle..

Comment: do not use $scope in this way `function setPrice($scope){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

**Html-Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="FooController">    
<input ng-model="foo.price" type="text" name="price"  class="price" id="price-min"  ng-init="foo.price = '100'"/>
```

**Angular-Code:**

```
var Foobar = angular.module('testapp', []);

Foobar.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.foo = {};
    setPrice($scope);

    function setPrice($scope) {
       $scope.foo.price = "400";
    }
}]);
```

The problem is that you don't have foo, yet. This is similar to writing

```
function test(){
    i=123;
}
```

See what's missing?

**However** when running this, the ng-init comes after the controller's instantiation. That means you're input has the value **100**

In Order to understand, please provide more information what you want to achieve (why the change?)...

Answer (score 1):

Try  modifying the controller as:

```
Foobar.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.setPrice = function() {
    $scope.foo = {'price': 200};
    return $scope.foo.price;
}
$scope.setPrice();

}]);
```

Comment: I am getting $scope.setPrice(); is not a function when doing this

Comment: Its not that it didn't work. I was looking for hogans solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do this

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="setPrice">
   <input ng-model="foo.price" type="text" name="price"  class="price" id="price-min" ng-init="foo.price = '100'" />

    <br/><br/>

  Hello, {{foo.price}}!
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

setPrice($scope);

function setPrice($scope) {
    var price = '200';
    $scope.foo = {
        price : price
    };
}
```

The error was the way you declare your **$scope.foo**

[Here the example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gumarelo/n9msuzsa/)

Comment: Why can't I just use $scope.foo.price = price?  What if I have multiple attributes like a name $scope.foo.name. Will they get overwritten?